# show summary of array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of denominations and each one has the ability to add a roll. When I click the button to add a role, it does the following:

```
$scope.addRoll = function (type) {
    $scope.rollArray.push({
        "type": type,
        "value": utilityFactory.getByLabel(type).clipValue
    });
}
```

The `HTML` output is currently

```
<ul class="rollList">
    <li ng-repeat="rolls in rollArray"><span>{{rolls.type}} | {{'$' + rolls.value.toFixed(2)}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Which looks like this on the UI

- pennies | $0.50
- pennies | $0.50
- pennies | $0.50

I would rather be able to show something like:

- 3 pennies | $1.50

Is there  way to use ng-repeat and group the elements that are the same and calculate the totals?

Comment: There isn't a way with the built in angular methods.  However, you could either write a custom directive for this although I feel that the better way would just be to create a method that would display a composite value.  I can post an example method if needed.

Comment: yes, that would be incredibly helpful!! My eyes are going to start bleeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the aggregate it could be as simple as an inverted index:

```
$scope.rollArray = [];
$scope.index = {};

var invertCounts = function(rollArray) {
    var object = {};

    for(var i in rollArray) {
        var type = rollArray[i].type;
        if(angular.isUndefined(object[type])) {
            object[type] = { count: 0, items: [], sum: 0.0 };
        }

        object[type].count++;
        object[type].items.push(rollArray[i]);
        object[type].sum += rollArray[i].value.toFixed(2)
    }

    return object;
}

$scope.addRoll = function (type) {
    $scope.rollArray.push({
        "type": type,
        "value": utilityFactory.getByLabel(type).clipValue
    });
    
    $scope.index = invertCounts($scope.rollArray);
};
```

with the following as the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(type, value) in invertCounts(rollArray)">
        {{ value.count + ' ' + type + ' -> ' + value.sum }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's not a perfect solution but it's a rough implementation of how you could do it.

### Update

My bad, that wouldn't work forgot about that just tested it in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcquillan314/8nfLtxsw/

Comment: getting error: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: that would only happen if you had an infinite loop.  Can you edit your code above with your controller and html?

Comment: I actually just copy/pasted what you have

Comment: I'm confused why there are two `$scope.addRoll`

Comment: Ah, there would only be one addRoll, sorry for the confusion. After you add the new roll to the array you would then make the call to regenerate the index.